# Grails - read regex from external properties file

Tags: regex, grails, properties, external

I have added an external properties file by adding the following the the Config.groovy file:

```
environments {
    production {
        grails.config.locations = ["file:./application-config.properties"]
    }
}
```

This works for some values (for example changing a URL that is used), however I have found that a regex will not work as expected. For example, if I had the following in Config.groovy:

```
regexes {
    deviceId = ~/\b[1-9][0-9]{6,7}\b/
}
```

a search for "1234567" will be resolved to being a deviceId.

However, if I add

```
regexes.deviceId = ~/\b[1-9][0-9]{2,3}\b/
```

to my application-config.properties file, it picks up that there is a change as "1234567" is no longer recognised as being a deviceId, yet "123" is not. (I have checked my regex with an online tool to check it's valid)

Why is this?
Is it possible to include a regex in my application-config.properties file? (I have also tried putting the regex in quotes)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that you can use the regex operator `~//` in a properties file. (I don't know a reason why it should not!)

But you can define a regex string and compile it explicit:

```
regexes.deviceId = "\\b[1-9][0-9]{2,3}\\b"
```

Be sure to use `\\` instead of `\` because Java/Groovy strings use `\` as the start for an excape character like `\n`... .

In your code use

```
var devIdRegEx = Pattern.compile([loaded regexes.deviceId property]);
...
```